# how to use orderBy after countBy?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two tables `products` and `votes` that each `product` can have multiple votes.

What I need is a total of votes for each product that are `orderBy DESC`.

This is my code:

```php
public function render()
{
    $pria = Product::find($this->product->id);
    $result = $pria->votes()
        ->get('voted')
        ->countBy('voted');

    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }

    return view('livewire.Raishomar');
}
```

I have total of votes, but how I can sorted it?

Comment: you need to sort product by total votes, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sortBy()` on the collection - but its much better to do this in SQL/Eloquent. Laravel offers a `withCount()` method on the querybuilder that you can utilize.

```php
$products = Product::withCount('votes')
                   ->orderBy('votes_count', 'desc')
                   ->get();
```

Your `$results` collection now has an additional property: `votes_count`. Before applying `->get()`, you can add any condition of `where()` you need to filter your query.